# Edit data and save it to database in Django

Tags: django, database, edit

I am a newbie.
I'm creating restaurant order management system which once the customer order food, the kitchen side can retrieve the customers' order and change the status of their food (example: cooked or ready to be served).

I want to edit the status of customers' order by using the select option, save it to database when i click "change status" button, and show it to kitchen_page.html page. But i am not sure how to do it?

Anyone can help me to do it?

Here is my templates: 
[image]

views.py:

```
def kitchen_view(request):
    chef_view = OrderItem.objects.all()
    #chef_view = OrderItem.objects.get(OrderId=OrderId)
    return render(request, 'restaurants/kitchen_page.html', {'chef_view': chef_view})
    if request.method == "POST":
        OrderId = request.POST.get("OrderId")
        Status = request.POST.get("Status")

        chef_view.OrderId = OrderId
        chef_view.Status = Status
        get_status = chef_view.save()

        return render(request, 'restaurants/kitchen_page.html', {'chef_view':chef_view})
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a render before anything happens.

```
def kitchen_view(request):
    chef_view = OrderItem.objects.all()
    # set the status if request method is post
    if request.method == "POST":
        order_id = request.POST.get("OrderId")
        status = request.POST.get("Status")
        # get order instance by id and change the status
        order = OrderItem.objects.get(pk=order_id)
        order.status = status
        order.save()
    # since the render data is the same, you can just call it once.
    return render(request, 'restaurants/kitchen_page.html', {'chef_view':chef_view})
```

Comment: i change it to your code, and it shows an error  The view customer.views.kitchen_view didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.  Do you know what is it and how to solve it?

Comment: you probably missed the last line or the indention is wrong. render should be outside of the if statement.

Comment: oh yes, my bad. Now, it shows an error name 'order_id' is not defined. Do you know what is it and how to solve it?

Comment: it says `order_id` isn't defined in your code. you probably missed that too!. check to code please. first line after if statement. Basically it's the id for your order. You should change it according to your model.

Comment: the id in my model is named as OrderId. then i change the order = OrderItem.objects.get(pk=OrderId), but it shows an error OrderItem matching query does not exist. OrderItem is my db name

Comment: if your order id is `OrderId` then you should change the code to this: `OrderItem.objects.get(OrderId=order_id)`

Comment: the error is simple. either you don't have the order id from request or you're doing the wrong query to get the order instance. please read django docs to understand how models works.